# webview_flutter just show a blank screen in android emulator

Tags: flutter, webview

Aftter installing **webview_flutter 0.3.19+9** library in my flatter project i want to use it so in order to i write these code :

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class ConfigWebViewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ConfigWebViewScreen(this._result);
  final dynamic _result;
  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://mc.iotel.ir/",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but noting is shown on my android emulator ??
other url like `https://stackoverflow.com/` is shown and webView is worked but it can't show https://mc.iotel.ir/ ?

This is printed in debug console:

```
D/EGL_emulation( 7360): eglMakeCurrent: 0xef2d8b80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe7779aa0)
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 2 (2) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 13 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/HostConnection( 7360): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xcfd0a4c0, tid 7648
D/HostConnection( 7360): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation( 7360): eglCreateContext: 0xd25680e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 7360): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd25680e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc2c9fc80)
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 2 (2) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
I/flutter ( 7360): Instance of 'CatalogsWithProductModel'
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
I/flutter ( 7360): Instance of 'CatalogsWithProductModel'
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 2 (2) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation( 7360): eglMakeCurrent: 0xef2d8b80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe7779aa0)
E/BufferQueueProducer( 7360): [SurfaceTexture-0-7360-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 2 (2) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon( 7360): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation( 7360): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd25680e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc2c9fc80)
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 0 0
D/eglCodecCommon( 7360): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
```

And in emulator just show a white screen!!

```
 flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    29.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor
      --android-licenses
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

***** Edit*******
When i good look to console i saw this error :

```
I/X509Util(27608): Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Comment: It can be because this website has an ssl certificate problem. You need to add intermediate certificate to solve it https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://mc.iotel.ir/ (otherwise, you can maybe use         android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest file)

Comment: There is `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in manifest app  and how can i add intermediate certificate?@Zeynal

Comment: Where did you buy the ssl certificate? They should also provide an intermediate certificate that you should add to the server.
I am not so sure about cleartextTraffic, it might not work at all.

Comment: This is what I get when I try your website in my webview,
"Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."


As I said, you need an intermediate/chain certificate.

Comment: Yes i saw this error and I added to my question @Zeynal

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? @sayres-kabir

Comment: Not yet. When i run app in real device this problem do not cause a problem and webview shows the web site but in emulator i can just see a blank screen @Zeynal

Comment: I think it depends on the webView of the mobile phone, and what web browser engine it is using. Did you check the website where you bought the SSL certificate? I believe, if you contact them and ask them for an intermediate/chain certificate they will provide you with one.